# Android app not working in few mobiles gionee pro, samsung j7, oppo

Tags: android

My client says that app not working in few mobiles G pro, Samsung j7, but it works for other phones.

When the app calls API from `HttpURLConnection` it's showing only progress dialog "Loading... please wait", it's not going ahead, it stuck at loading.
The build gradle is using the following:

```
compile Version 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
min Version 15
target Version 25
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: not working for gionee pro, oppo mobiles, samsung j7, plz help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry guys, that issue is because of reliance jio